# WordPress: Function changing number of posts displayed in archives.php not working

Tags: php, wordpress, archive, categories

Trying to extend the number of posts shown in archive pages (archives/tags/categories/etc.) Even though I'm using this function it still only displays 4, any ideas what is wrong? I have tried with the `wp_reset_query();` function both before `$posts` and at the start of the function:

Archive.php:

```
    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

        <?php 
            $post = $posts[0]; // Hack. Set $post so that the_date() works. 
            ?>

        <?php /* If this is a category archive */ if (is_category()) { ?>   
<div class="bumper">&nbsp;</div>    
    <div id="mainContent" class="clearfix">
        <div id="archiveWrap" class="clearfix">
            <h2>Test1.3: <?php single_cat_title(); ?>sarkiv</h2>

        <?php /* If this is a tag archive */ } elseif( is_tag() ) { ?>
            <h3>Posts Tagged &#8216;<?php single_tag_title(); ?>&#8217;</h3>

        <?php /* If this is a daily archive */ } elseif (is_day()) { ?>
            <h><?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?></h3>

        <?php /* If tahis is a monthly archive */ } elseif (is_month()) { ?>
            <h3><?php the_time('F, Y'); ?></h3>

        <?php /* If this is a yearly archive */ } elseif (is_year()) { ?>
            <h3> <?php the_time('Y'); ?></h3>

        <?php /* If this is an author archive */ } elseif (is_author()) { ?>
            <h3>Author Archive</h3>

        <?php /* If this is a paged archive */ } elseif (isset($_GET['paged']) && !empty($_GET['paged'])) { ?>
            <h3>Blog Archives</h3>

        <?php } ?>

        <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/inc/nav.php' ); ?>

        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

            <div <?php post_class() ?>>

                <h3 id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>

                <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/inc/meta.php' ); ?>

                <div class="entry">
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                </div>

            </div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>


        <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/inc/nav.php' ); ?>

<?php else : ?>

    <h3>Nothing found</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

functions.php:

```
 function post_per_page_control( $query ) {

         if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() )
           return;

        // Archive
         if ( is_archive() ) {
              //control the numbers of post displayed/listed (eg here 10)
              $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 10 );
              return;   
         }
          // Category
         if ( is_category() ) {
              //control the numbers of post displayed/listed (eg here 10)
              $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 10 );
              return;   
         }


         // Tag
         if ( is_tag() ) {
              //control the numbers of post displayed/listed (eg here 10)
              $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 10 );
              return;
         }
      }
      add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'post_per_page_control' );
```

Comment: Try to set a lower hook priority, like 1

Comment: Sry, "hook priority"? I'm feeling lost here.

Comment: The four parameter of `add_action` is the hook priority (a lower number will execute your code earlier, an higher one will execute it later - default priority is 10), the third is the number of parameters expected by the function. For example: `add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'post_per_page_control', 1, 1);` - if it doesn't help try an higher one then (like 20).